# How to cbind vectors of different length in R?

Tags: r, vector, cbind

I need to combine some named numeric vectors in R into a data frame. I tried `cbind.na` as suggestet in another question, but it would not take names into account. Example:

```
v1 <- c(1,5,6,7)
names(v1) <- c("milk", "flour", "eggs", "sugar")
v2 <- c(2,3)
names(v2) <- c("fish", "chips")
v3 <- c(5,7,4)
names(v3) <- c("chips", "milk", "sugar")
```

The data frame should look like this

```
       v1    v2     v3
milk   1     NA     7
flour  5     NA     NA
eggs   6     NA     NA
sugar  7     NA     4
fish   NA    2      NA
chips  NA    3      5
```

I can't figure out how to solve this in R.

Comment: @RichardHardy I'm sorry. I didn't  know.

Comment: No worries! I am just explaining why you might not get the answer you are looking for. Perhaps try some R-specific site instead.

Comment: I think you are trying to make a labeled factor or what are the columns mean in this case?

Comment: try bind_cols from dplyr.

Comment: You'll need to perform a `full_join` from the dplyr package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a join, best done with `data.table` or other add-ins, but (especially for smallish arrays) can readily be performed in base `R` by creating an array of all the names and using it to index into the input arrays:

```
s <- unique(names(c(v1,v2,v3)))
x <- cbind(v1=v1[s], v2=v2[s], v3=v3[s])
rownames(x) <- s
print(x)
```

> ```
>       v1 v2 v3
> milk   1 NA  7
> flour  5 NA NA
> eggs   6 NA NA
> sugar  7 NA  4
> fish  NA  2 NA
> chips NA  3  5
> ```

Comment: Nice approach. You can vectorize it so you don't have to type out all the variable names (in case there are > 3): `v <- mget(paste0('v', 1:3));
s <- unique(unlist(lapply(v, names)));
x <- data.frame(s, lapply(v, '[', s))`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thank you.  I considered doing that but thought it might obscure the answer: it's nice to see `cbind` appear prominently in the solution.  But for the generalization to many arrays something like your approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
# get vectors into one list
v <- mget(paste0('v', 1:3))
# convert vectors to data frames
l <- lapply(v, stack)
# merge them all sequentially
out <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 'ind', all = T), l)
# name the columns according to the original vector names
setNames(out, c('ind', names(v)))

#     ind v1 v2 v3
# 1  milk  1 NA  7
# 2 flour  5 NA NA
# 3  eggs  6 NA NA
# 4 sugar  7 NA  4
# 5  fish NA  2 NA
# 6 chips NA  3  5
```

Edit:
I think this is worse than whuber's solution because it requires creating a bunch of intermediate tables, both in the lapply step and in the Reduce step. Haven't done any benchmarks though.